# string slicing, php

Tags: php, string, tokenize

is there a way to slice a string lets say i have this variable

```
$output=Country=UNITED STATES (US) &City=Scottsdale, AZ &Latitude=33.686 &Longitude=-111.87
```

i want to slice it in a way i want to pull latitude and longitude values in to seperate variables, subtok is not serving the purpose

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression for this; use `explode()` to split up the string, first by `&`, and then by `=`, which you can use to effectively parse it into a nice little array mapping names to values.

Comment: could you please give an example of the above? Thanks.

Comment: $var_array = explode('&', $var_string);
foreach($var_array as $var_to_split)

Comment: I messed up that last entry by hitting enter. Not a fan of that style of auto-submit. And now it doesn't seem to wrap the following in a pre-code block no matter what I try


`    // Separate the strings into individual vars
    $var_array = explode('&', $var_string); 
    $mapped_var_array = array(); // Set up this to hold mapped vars
    foreach($var_array as $var_to_split){
        $var_to_split = explode('=', $var_to_split);
        $mapped_var_array[$var_to_split[0]] = $var_to_split[1];
    }

    // Now do whatever you want with $mapped_var_array
`
Something like that.
@hitautodestruct

Comment: Thanks alot @prayfomojo. I also added your comment to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
$output='Country=UNITED STATES (US) &City=Scottsdale, AZ &Latitude=33.686 &Longitude=-111.87';
parse_str($output, $array);
$latitude = $array['latitude'];
```

You could also just do

```
parse_str($output);
echo $latitude;
```

I think using an array is better as you are not creating variables all over the place, which could potentially be dangerous (like register_globals) if you don't trust the input string.

Answer (score 2):

It looks likes it's coming from an URL, although the URL encoding is gone.

I second the suggestions of using [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/explode) or [`preg_split()`](http://www.php.net/preg_split) but you might also be interested in [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/parse_str).

```
$output = "City=Scottsdale, AZ &Latitude=33.686 &Longitude=-111.87";
parse_str($output, $results);
$lat = $results['Latitude'];
$lon = $results['Longitude'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're demonstrating in your code, maybe it's just some typos, is the "$output" the name of the variable, or part of the string?

Assuming it's the name of the variable, and you just forgot to put the quotes on the string, you have a couple options:

---

```
$sliced = explode('&', $output)
```

This will create an array with values: "Country=UNITED STATES(US) ", "City=Scottsdale, AZ ", etc.

---

```
$sliced = preg_split('/[&=]/', $output);
```

This will create an array with alternating elements being the "variables" and their values: "Country", "UNITED STATES(US) ", "City", "Scottsdale, AZ ", etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
$output = 'Country=UNITED STATES (US) &City=Scottsdale, AZ &Latitude=33.686 &Longitude=-111.87';

$strs = explode('&', $output);
foreach ($strs as $str) {

   list($var, $val) = explode('=',$str);
   $$var = trim($val);

}
```

This would give you variables such as $Latitude and $Longitude that are set to the value in the key/value pair.

Comment: Variable variables? Please no :(

Comment: This is a really bad idea. What if your keys contain spaces? PHP's associative arrays make more sense here:
$array[$var] = trim($val);

Answer (score 0):

All of the other Answers are Insufficient. This Should Work Every Time!

```
function slice($string, $start){
  $st = $string; $s = $start; $l = strlen($st); $a = func_get_args();
  $e = isset($a[2]) ? $a[2] : $l;
  $f = $e-$s;
  $p = $e < 0 && $s > 0 ? $l+$f : $f;
  return substr($st, $s, $p);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you read about regular expressions in the PHP help.