# php string to array and split

Tags: php, string

Looking for suggestions as to the best way to do this (I know there are many options):

take a variable like this:

```
$args = ('post_type=post&order_by=DESC&limit=10');
```

the create a function to convert that variable into parts like this:

```
$post_type = post;
$order_by = DESC;
$limit= 10;
```

Reason is I want a client to be able to use a string like the first to pass variables to a sql query in much the same way (but doesn't have to be exact) as you can do it in WordPress.

Comment: possible duplicate of [string slicing, php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587872/string-slicing-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at

[http_build_query()](http://php.net/http_build_query)

and

[parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) ( in your case it's more `parse_str()` but you'll need the first one for "doing the opposite" )

Comment: Thanks kemo, totally forgot parse_str() - durrrr.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [`parse_str`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function can help you.

```
$query = parse_str($args);
$post_type = $query['post_type'];
$order_by = $query['order_by'];
$limit = $query['limit'];
```